# ng-repeat to create the hyperlink

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue to create the list of hyperlink using the ng-repeat.
I have the user.spaces has a array of objects like

```
user.spaces is [
{device_name: 'phone1',
 id : '11111'
},
{device_name: 'phone2',
 id='22222'
]

and I want to create the list of device_name's hyper link like below
List of devices :

        phone1
        phone2
```

and here is the code in .html file

```
<div ng-if="userController.inEdit" class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4">{{'USER.WORKSPACE_USER' | translate}}:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <tr ng-repeat="space in user.spaces track by $index">
      <td><a href ng-click="goToSpace(space)" id="linkSpaces_{{$index}}" >{{space.device_name}}</a></td>
    </tr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Didn't get the result that I want like the list of device's hyper links.
Any suggestions that what need to change in the .html file to make it works
Thanks In advance,
Kim

Comment: What do you get? If error show your console error

Comment: it didn't create any hyperlink even though spaces have array length of 5

Comment: What version of angular js are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in an href attribute will make the link go to the wrong URL if the user clicks it before Angular has a chance to replace the {{hash}} markup with its value. Until Angular replaces the markup the link will be broken and will most likely return a 404 error. The ngHref directive solves this problem.

**Also the = operator is missing in your code**

```
<td><a id="linkSpaces_{{$index}}" href>{{space.device_name}}</a></td>
```

**Change it to**

```
<td><a id="linkSpaces_{{$index}}" ng-href="reference">{{space.device_name}}</a></td>
```

**The wrong way to write it:**

```
<a href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}">link1</a>
```

**The correct way to write it:**

```
<a ng-href="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{hash}}">link1</a>
```

see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref for better explanation how to use it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Actually I want to have the click event . See the update code above

Answer (score 0):

check it.

JS :

```
$scope.user={ 
             spaces : [
                        { device_name: 'phone1', id : '11111' },
                        {device_name: 'phone2', id:'22222'}
                      ]
            };

$scope.goToSpace = function(oneDevice){
        console.log(oneDevice)    
    }
```

HTML :

```
<tr ng-repeat="space in user.spaces track by $index">
      <td><a href ng-click="goToSpace(space)" id="linkSpaces_{{$index}}" >{{space.device_name}}</a></td>
    </tr>
```